# Advanced AVERAGEIF

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Screenshot from Excel]

I want to find out the average of the revenue from all the people that met their individual quota. How can I achieve this? By using

```
=AVERAGEIF(B2:B9;">"&C2)
```

I only find out the ones that had a revenue more than cell `C2`, which is not what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B9*(B2:B9>=C2:C9))/SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B9>=C2:C9))
```

This will sum those that met the Quota and divide that by the count of those that met the quota.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do this with AVERAGEIF, but here is a workaround using AVERAGE and IF:
https://www.equalto.com/suresheet/view/100f0181-eaa3-4668-8344-5999d63d5880

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).